# Are hardware drivers needed to be installed on the management OS of a type 1 hypervisor?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, linux-kvm

Type 2 hypervisors such as VMware Workstation run virtual machines on top of a host OS. Only the the host needs hardware drivers, while the guests do not as they are running on virtual hardware.

On the contrary, type 1 hypervisors like Windows Hyper-V and Linux's KVM run on bare-metal hardware, with all guests equal to each other. The management OS has a little more power, that is to interact with the hypervisor to create and manage other guests.

[image]

With the management OS itself running on top of the hypervisor, do we really need to install hardware drivers on it?

Comment: You would only need drivers for devices used by ESXi or Hyper-V Server, otherwise, the VMs work identically to that have VMWare Workstation and Hyper-V within Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both types of hypervisors behave similarly : they virtualize the hardware
and pass those virtual devices on to the VM. The VM then needs native drivers
to these virtual devices exposed by the hypervisor.

The only difference is that Type 1 needs its own drivers for the hardware,
while Type 2 uses the drivers supplied by the host OS.

Comment: The type 1 hypervisor runs below the management OS and provide virtual hardware to it. How can a driver installation on the management OS affect the hypervisor? Because a VM cannot see the underlying "real" hardware.

Comment: Depends on the type 1 hypervisor, for example Windows 10 Hyper-V's parent partition has different access to the hardware then regular VMs. A VM can see the underlying hardware in some cases and does see it for certain hardware, like the CPU.  Your question's answer is more complex than you're making it out to be.

Comment: Passthrough devices do exist on some products, and it's a long story whatever works and what doesn't. The question here, if developed, can occupy a small book to answer. The main difference is if the hypervisor needs to drive the hardware itself, and which devices it passes on to the VMs. In all cases, the VM needs drivers for these virtual devices, so almost all operating systems today support the drivers required for all major virtualization products. In short, for all types of hypervisors native drivers are required - drivers for the virtual devices (unless passthrough exist for some).